# Why is .NET ObservableCollection<T> implemented as a class and not an interface?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, observablecollection

In reading about the Observer design pattern, I noticed that it is implemented using interfaces.  In Java, the java.util.observable implementation is also a class.  Shouldn't the C# and Java versions use interfaces ?

Scott

Comment: How can you "implement as an interface"? If something is already implemented, it is a class, isn't it? An interface isn't implemented on its own.

Comment: However, the meaning of the question stands. There is a huge gap in the .net collection object graph with ObservableCollection<T>. Its functionality should have been separated into different interfaces in order to allow extensibility in a more flexible way. For example, if I implement an ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : INotifyCollectionChanged, I cannot use it as a source for ReadOnlyObservableCollection<TValue>. The current implementation is not pattern based and does not support pattern based development at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. However, interestingly, it *doesn't* implement the new [`IObservable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) interface from .NET 4.0, which you might have expected.

It would arguably be useful for there to be a generic form of `INotifyCollectionChanged`... but I don't know of one.

Comment: So, I actually tried this, and it ends up being really ugly if you do it directly since any class that implements both IObservable<T> and IEnumerable<T> get *both* Rx and Linq extensions - lots of casting and gnashing of teeth. However, you could implement AsObservable() as an Extension Method pretty easily

Answer (score 2):

But they DO use interfaces. The ObservableCollection in .NET is an implementation of the interfaces - you are free to ignore it and to your own implementation.